# Can I download someone's repository and upload it to my GitHub account?

Tags: git, github

I want to download someone's repository to my local machine and upload it to my GitHub account. Will there be some issues if I upload it to my GitHub?

How can I do this?

I researched but I can't find the exact solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is simply to perform a fork.....

https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo

It will allow you later on to get the updated changes as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can download and upload to your repository. You can use any of the options to download.

[image: download repo]

After downloading change the origin of this git to your repo.

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git
# Set a new remote

$ git remote -v
# Verify new remote
> origin  https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
> origin  https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

Comment: Note that if you choose "Download ZIP", it's not the same as clonging because it doesn't download a Git repo. You'll get "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git" if you try to run Git commands on the contents of the ZIP file. It's best to just clone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can do it.

##### Downloading a Repository:

1. Go to the GitHub repository you want to clone.
2. Click the "Fork" button at the top right to create a copy in your GitHub account.
3. Copy the repository's URL from your forked repository (use HTTPS or SSH).
4. Open your terminal/command prompt.
5. Use `git clone` to download the repository to your local machine:

   ```bash
   git clone repository-url
   ```
6. Navigate to the cloned repository:

   ```bash
   cd repository-name
   ```
7. Make any changes you need.

##### Uploading to Your GitHub Account:

8. Commit your changes:

   ```bash
   git add .
   git commit -m "Your commit message here"
   ```
9. Push changes to your fork:

   ```bash
   git push origin main
   ```
10. Create a pull request from your forked repository to the original repository.
11. Wait for approval or merge by the repository owner.

Comment: Step 10 and 11 is not needed if you just want to fork the repo to your own account. You are not required to make a PR to the original repo. You can, but it's only really needed if you want to copy changes to the original repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the entire repository including all branches, then you might want to use the `--mirror` option.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Source repository URL
SOURCE_REPO="https://source-git-server/source-username/source-repository.git"

# GitHub repository URL (replace with your GitHub repository URL)
GITHUB_REPO="https://github.com/your-username/github-repository.git"

# Clone the source repository
git clone --mirror "$SOURCE_REPO" source_mirror

# Navigate to the source mirror
cd source_mirror

# Fetch updates from the source repository
git fetch --prune

# Push changes to the GitHub repository
git push --mirror "$GITHUB_REPO"

# Clean up
cd ..
rm -rf source_mirror
```

Replace the script with appropriate values, and you should be able to mirror the entire repository into your GitHub repository. This includes all branches and tags.

More details on this topic at [Github Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/duplicating-a-repository#mirroring-a-repository-in-another-location)